# Objective-C using inherited variables & overriding inherited properties

Tags: objective-c

(ARC is enabled)

lets say I have a class names BasicGameCard in it declared the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger cardValue;
```

Then I create a derived class WarGameCard : BasicGameCard.

WarGameCard extends with a suit property and wishes to use the inherited cardValue to represent its rank 
Questions:

1. how can i use/call in `WarGameCard` class the variable `_cardValue` without using the property?

   a) writing `_cardValue` in `WarGameCard`: results in compiler error (i guess there is no 
     protected Access modifier in objective-c and the variable is private)

   b) can't use `self.cardValue` it will compile but will cause an infinite loop calling the 
     setter

   c) tried to write the following in `WarGameCard`: `@synthesize cardValue = _cardValue;`
     but when debugging i see 2 different variables one of super class and one of the derived
     each with different value
2. What is the right way to override inherited properties

Answer (score 13):

In your subclass, use the inherited accessors `cardValue` and `setCardValue:` to get and set the inherited value. You don't need to override the value; you just need to use it.

Once your subclass *consistently* uses the accessors, then you can override the accessors if you want. For example

```
 - (void) setCardValue: (NSInteger) newValue
 {
      [super setValue: newValue];
      [self celebratePromotion];
 }
```

You're correct: in Objective C there's no protected inheritance.  But modern objective-C uses accessors far more extensively than C++. In fact, outside constructors and destructors and (arguably) accessors, you should never touch instance variables directly.

Comment: `Objective C there's no protected inheritance.` I don't think it's correct. The default modifier of a instance variable will be @protected and can be used in subclass. The only thing should do is put the instance declaration to the header. But in modern Objective-C, there is no necessary to declare instance vars in header(complier helps you and declares them in .m file), so you cannot directly access to a instance var. Just use the accessors will be OK. @MarkBernstein +1.

Comment: @onevcat: correct. There is a protected inheritance in ObjC, but as Mark Bernstein notes, you generally should not. Just use the accessors.

Comment: There's protected inheritance of instance variables, true.  But there's no protected inheritance of methods, which is what someone accustomed to (say) C++ would be looking for.  And since there are good reasons never to avoid using naked instance variables, it's really easy to forget @protected exists!

Comment: @MarkBernstein, excellent point. "Inheritance" obviously means methods, and there is no such thing as a protected method in ObjC, just protected ivars.

Comment: Protected inheritance of instance variables by default @onevcat? Are you sure? I would think the underlying iVar of a property is synthesized to be @private, and when you call `self.someProperty = someValue` in a subclass, you're really calling `[self setSomeProperty:someValue]` in the superclass, which in turn sets the iVar. If they were @protected by default, you'd be able to access _someProperty in subclasses. I could also be misunderstanding what you meant. Maybe you're talking about iVars in general, and not the underlying iVars of properties.